# Drawing an area chart in React with colors based on the values

Tags: reactjs, graph, recharts

I'm making a monitoring application where you can make health checks of your websites, API endpoints etc. and I need to draw a chart with response times as a value. I've used recharts to do that, but I couldn't change the color of areas where the value was bigger than 500ms, I can't find any library that is capable of doing this, and it's very important feature to me. Can anyone recommend some library that can do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recharts should be capable of doing that when talking about

- line colors
  https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-basic-line-chart-with-different-colors-static-gradients-bno3p
- bar colors:
  https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/280

If you want to change area fillings based on the values, this is afaik not possible with recharts (currently). I know about ApexCharts that is capable of doing so with some additional logic.

Here you can find a good example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-forked-x6ii8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!